# Create a SuiteTalk transaction search that gets all sales order with a certain status

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

In NetSuite SuiteTalk (Web Services), I am trying to create a search that will find all sales orders that have the status "Pending Approval".  I think I have everything structured correctly and I think the problem is the status is not actually called "Pending Approval, but something else.  I have tried other variants like "_pendingApproval", but my search never returns any results.  If I comment out the status part, the search works correctly and returns every sales order for this particular customer.

Any thoughts on what the problem is?

```
C#


TransactionSearchBasic tsb = new TransactionSearchBasic() {
    mainLine = new SearchBooleanField() {
        searchValue = true,
        searchValueSpecified = true,
    },
    type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
        @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        operatorSpecified = true,
        searchValue = new string[] { "_salesOrder" },    
    },
    entity = new SearchMultiSelectField() {
        @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        operatorSpecified = true,
        searchValue = new RecordRef[] {
            new RecordRef() {
                type = RecordType.customer,
                internalId = "231"
            }
        }
    },
    status = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
        @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        operatorSpecified = true,
        searchValue = new string[] {
            "Pending Approval",
            "_pendingApproval",
            "pendingApproval",
            "pendingapproval",
            "pending approval",
            "0"
        }
    }
};

SearchResult results = _nss.search(tsb);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the type of transaction needs to be prefixed to the status.  For example:

```
status = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
    @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
    operatorSpecified = true,
    searchValue = new string[] {
        "_salesOrderPendingApproval"
    }

}
```

Comment: For future reference, instead of putting a hard-coded string, you should use one of the static fields in TransactionStatus. This way, you can even get guidance from the auto-complete feature of your IDE.

Comment: Do you mean the enum TransactionStatuses?  I tried that and the ones in SalesOrderStatuses, but they never return a result.  I could only get it to work with the string.

Comment: You're right, it's not there! I was thinking of the Java binding (which helpfully has the string defined as a static field) and assumed C# would be similar. But looking at the C# version, that string doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
"pendingApproval"
```

instead of

```
"_pendingApproval" & "Pending Approval"
```

Comment: I tried that and a few more variations but still no luck.  I updated my question with the variations I tried.

Comment: I figured this out.  It needs to be "_salesOrderPendingApproval".

Comment: @user3075978 glad to know you figured it out. You can accept your own answer. Infact I was also unaware of that. This will definitely help others.